# Recurring Direct Debit Donation Amount Changes Not Reported on CiviCRM Bank Reconciliation

Tags: recurring-contributions, payment, repeating-events

We encountered an issue that when changes are made to a donor's contribution amount before a ACH/EFT run, the amount is reflected by the bank, but is not updating when running a bank reconciliation report in CiviCRM for that given run.

Example:

1. Donation is $10
2. Donor requests a change to $20
3. When the donation is processed, the bank shows that $20 was indeed processed, but the CiviCRM bank reconciliation report shows the donor's contribution as $10.
4. The tax receipt amount, however, is showing $20.

Any thoughts on what would cause this? Has anyone encountered this? Do we have to re-enter the recurring donation every time a change needs to be made?

Thank you for any assistance!

David

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  CiviCRM doesn't have a built-in bank reconciliation report, so this is probably something someone set up for you.  Do you know which report template it uses?  And could you edit your question to include which payment processor you use? Thanks!